How to Integrate Telegram Login Widget with Custom Authentication in FastAPI?
I am developing a project with FastAPI and I want to implement authentication using the Telegram Login Widget. The FastAPI documentation demonstrates a traditional approach with OAuth2PasswordBearer and OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, but I need to implement a custom authentication scheme because my users will authenticate using the Telegram Login Widget.
After authentication, I receive a dictionary of user data from the Telegram server, along with a hash signature, which I verify to validate the user. The problem is integrating this custom logic into FastAPI and configuring Swagger to work with this scheme, accepting a TelegramAuthRequest object that contains the Telegram data instead of a username and password.
Code Example:
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import jwt, JWTError
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

from app.database import get_db
from app.config import JWT_ALGORITHM, JWT_SECRET_KEY, BOT_TOKEN
from app.models import Users
from app.services.telegram.auth_widget import check_integrity

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/auth",
    tags=["auth"],
)

oauth2_bearer = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="auth/token")

class TelegramAuthRequest(BaseModel):
    id: int
    first_name: str
    last_name: str | None = None
    username: str | None = None
    photo_url: str | None = None
    auth_date: int
    hash: str

class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str

db_dependency = Annotated[Session, Depends(get_db)]


def authenticate_user(user_auth_data: dict, db):
    user_id = user_auth_data.get("id")
    user = db.query(Users).filter(Users.id == user_id).first()
    if not user:
        return False
    if not check_integrity(BOT_TOKEN, user_auth_data):
        return False
    return user

def create_access_token(user_id: str, user_role: str, expires_delta: timedelta):
    encode = {"id": user_id, "role": user_role}
    expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + expires_delta
    encode.update({"exp": expire})
    return jwt.encode(encode, JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithm=JWT_ALGORITHM)
    
async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_bearer)]):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[JWT_ALGORITHM])
        user_id = payload.get("id")
        user_role = payload.get("role")
        if user_id is None or user_role is None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                detail="Could not validate user.")
        return {"id": user_id, "role": user_role}
    except JWTError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            detail="Could not validate user.")

@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(telegram_auth_request: TelegramAuthRequest,
                                 db: db_dependency):
    telegram_auth = telegram_auth_request.model_dump()
    user = authenticate_user(telegram_auth, db)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            detail="Could not validate user.")
    token = create_access_token(user.id, user.role, timedelta(days=7))

    return {"access_token": token, "token_type": "bearer"}

Current Swagger Authorization UI
I implemented a custom TelegramAuthRequest model to receive data from Telegram and wrote an authenticate_user function that checks data integrity. I also implemented JWT token generation for authenticated users. However, I encountered difficulties integrating this logic with FastAPI’s security system and configuring Swagger to display this custom authentication scheme.
I understand that the current behavior is due to using OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="auth/token"), as shown in the attached screenshot. However, I need to change the authorization scheme to accept a TelegramAuthRequest object, not username and password
